# Nodejs limit the API access to hosted web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, vuejs2

[image]

I have a hosted admin panel under the domain `admin.foo.com` and the API hosted under the domain `api.foo.com`

I have an open endpoint `GET - api.foo.com/all-products`. There is no authentication header required to access this resource. But this should be accessed only via the hosted web app.

The user should not be able to copy this url and paste on the web browser and see the json response and also user should not be able the data from this endpoint via another API or something.

This question is already asked in StackOverflow but the given answer is this is not possible due to powerful tools like postmon. But this should be able to achieve to at least for some extent using Node.js and express.js features.

Say check where the request is coming from and then block the resource something like that. How do I achieve this using Node.js, Express.js?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is cors

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://admin.foo.com'
}));
```

More info: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/

Comment: Probably the closest thing to an answer for this question. This will prevent other sites from requesting data from the API, however it will not stop the user from going directly to api.foo.com or stop them from using scripts to access the site (I don't believe those are possible at all—perhaps preventing direct access through a browser, but not through a script— although authentication would help ensure only authorized users are accessing the site).